# Create metadata subterm with powershell pnp

Tags: pnp-powershell

I am trying to create a script that will add a few subterms in an existing term in my term store. I have managed to use new-pnpterm and create a term at the same level as my other terms , I've still haven't figured out how to create a subterm , any pointers please?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question , this is easier with Import-PNPTaxonomy

e.g

Import-PnPTaxonomy TermGroup|TermSet|Term|SubTerm

Comment: I am also in need of the same solution. but for me, I also need to add custom properties so I can not use "Import-PnPTaxonomy". Is there a way I can add child term with custom properties